# System Restart Upon Building in Xcode 11

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode

I'm a beginner Swift developer and this is my first question in Stack Overflow. I've been working on an iOS SpriteKit game in Swift 5, Xcode 11 (updated from Xcode 10.3 as of a week ago). Aside increasing build times over the past few months, everything has been running smoothly.

About a week ago, running my application on any device or simulator began crashing my computer, forcing a restart with a large '!' icon in the background behind text explaining "There was an issue", with a normal startup and login process following. I would receive a dialog explaining "MacBook Pro experienced an issue and had to restart" and I was offered to report the crash to Apple (which I did).

This first occurred when I tried to archive a version of my app. I did research and found that deleting the `DerivedData` folder from `User/Library/Developer/Xcode` and the `xcuserdata` folder from both the project file and the workspace file contents prevented the crash after cleaning the build folder.

Then the same issue arose when I attempted to run my application on my iPhone 8. This time, performing the steps above solved nothing. This time, I analyzed the program instead of running it, which worked. Then, after a day, analyzing caused the system restart. So did a ton of other methods I tried. Up until now, all of the following actions result in a system restart after about 3-5 minutes of starting:

- Building and running
- Archiving
- Analyzing
- Building for Testing

In addition, I've tried the above methods after deleting said folders and cleaning the build folder. I've also tried them on the simulators, physical devices, and the Generic iOS Device. Nothing seems to be working.

Below is the system log that occurred during the crash. It is the one that my computer offered to send to Apple. I replaced a portion of the output with `[...]` as Stack Overflow detected some parts as spam. Willing to provide if needed.

I'm running macOS Mojave 10.14.6 on a 2017 MacBookPro. The latest occurence of this error occurs in Xcode Version 11.0 (11A420a), yet the forced restart issue also arose in Xcode 10.3 and Xcode 11 GM Seed 2.

If additional information is needed, I'll be happy to provide it.

```
Anonymous UUID:       44******-****-****-****-**********92

Sat Sep 21 21:31:12 2019

*** Panic Report ***
mp_kdp_enter() timed-out on cpu 0, NMI-ing
mp_kdp_enter() NMI pending on cpus: 0 2
mp_kdp_enter() timed-out during locked wait after NMI;expected 4 acks but received 3 after 9361562 loops in 1548000000 ticks
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff80009ecea8): "thread_call group 'high' reached max thread cap (500): active: 1, blocked: 499, idle: 0"@/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/xnu/xnu-4903.271.2/osfmk/kern/thread_call.c:221
Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address
[...]

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task

Mac OS version:
18G95

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 18.7.0: Tue Aug 20 16:57:14 PDT 2019; root:xnu-4903.271.2~2/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: C41337A1-0EC3-3896-A954-A1F85E849D53
Kernel slide:     0x0000000000600000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8000800000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8000700000
System model name: MacBookPro14,2 (Mac-CAD6701F7CEA0921)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 5389100927958
last loaded kext at 4928689757019: com.apple.filesystems.msdosfs    1.10 (addr 0xffffff7f841db000, size 69632)
last unloaded kext at 305554353504: com.apple.filesystems.msdosfs   1.10 (addr 0xffffff7f841db000, size 61440)
loaded kexts:
com.Cycling74.driver.Soundflower    2
com.valvesoftware.SteamInput    3083.39.62
com.apple.filesystems.msdosfs   1.10
com.apple.fileutil  20.036.15
[...]
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
com.apple.kec.Libm  1

EOF
Model: MacBookPro14,2, BootROM 198.71.1.0.0, 2 processors, Intel Core i5, 3.1 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 2.44f1
Graphics: kHW_IntelIrisGraphics650Item, Intel Iris Plus Graphics 650, spdisplays_builtin
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, LPDDR3, 2133 MHz, 0x80CE, 0x4B3445364533303445422D45474347202020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, LPDDR3, 2133 MHz, 0x80CE, 0x4B3445364533303445422D45474347202020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x171), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.77.61.2 AirPortDriverBrcmNIC-1305.8)
Bluetooth: Version 6.0.14d3, 3 services, 18 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus
USB Device: Flash Disk
USB Device: Apple T1 Controller
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 41.1
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 41.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like I figured it out on my own. I'm going to post the solution here in case any other Xcode developers run into the same issue.

It seems as though the problem lies in the project's directory. Because the entire Xcode project was on a USB disk drive, build times were slowing and restarts were occurring. **To fix the issue, I simply created a copy of my project on my computer's drive and ran the program.** Everything worked just fine. In fact, build times were much faster.

Comment: Very interesting, but this answer does not grow out of the question because the USB drive wasn't mentioned anywhere. Also, it's hard to see how this is a _programming_ question; perhaps Ask Different would be a better forum?

Comment: Ok, duly noted. I didn't mention the USB because I did not think that would play a factor in why it crashed, but I was incorrect. Next time I have a question related to a situation like this I will post on Ask Different.

Comment: No problem. As I said, this is certainly interesting. I'm not surprised that things are lot faster if you're doing everything from the internal disk, but the restarts are surprising and in my opinion this would warrant a bug report to Apple, especially because this is new behavior in Xcode 11. Go to https://feedbackassistant.apple.com to file the report.